# How optimize SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `trades`
WHERE `symbol` = 'ICX/BTC' AND `timestamp` >= :since AND `timestamp` <= :until
ORDER BY `timestamp`
LIMIT 50000
```

It's take long time to execute (more 5 min). 
I have index by **symbol** and **timestamp** columns

How I can optimize this query?

Comment: Do you need all the properties of `trades`? One way of cutting down the execution time is to only select the properties you need. In other words, write `SELECT * FROM` more specific.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is really the thing slowing it down, ordering by all 50K rows is the bulk of the work in the query

Comment: Put it in a (cachable) View.

Comment: Please post the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE trades`) and the `EXPLAIN` result. This is the minimum of information for SQL performance questions.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trades AS t
WHERE t.symbol = 'ICX/BTC' AND t.timestamp >= :since AND t.timestamp <= :until
ORDER BY t.timestamp
LIMIT 50000;
```

(which I just rewrite a bit so I can follow it more easily)

You want an index on `trades(symbol, timestamp)`.

However, you appear to be selecting a very large number of rows, so this might still take a long time.  The index should be used both for the `WHERE` clause and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Is the query in this response different from the one in the question? Just asking out of curiosity because they look the same to me except yours is using the abbreviated t ? Also where is t defined in your query? thx

Comment: Above 40 millions rows in table. Yes, I try use **symbol** in ORDER clause

Comment: Yes the t table alias executes the same as your query.. But you should make it a habit of using table aliases or fully quantifyed table names within MySQL so MySQL can never mix up the columns if you use co-related subquery or inner queries @Dan

Comment: But why are you editing this answer to "fix" it? Seems a bit liberal as an edit, should be up to OP to make that type of edit.  Anyway I was mostly just asking initially because I didn't understand the answer fully, trying to get clarification to learn.

Comment: As I said, my table has index on symbol and timestamp
    CREATE INDEX IDX_trades_symbol_timestamp ON trades(`symbol`, `timestamp`)

Comment: "But why are you editing this answer to "fix" it? Seems a bit liberal as an edit, should be up to OP to make that type of edit." Because stackoverflow allows this kind of edit if you have enough of reputation points. I only edit answers to improve them this is pretty much normal on stackoverflow @Dan

Comment: eh, I dont know if that edit really qualifies as a valid edit...I make edits too and I have reputation points to do so but I don't go in changing people's answers or fixing their typos.  Anyway, I'm not trying to argue I was genuinely curious about the original reply, thx for the info.

Comment: For what it's worth Gordon Linoff and Raymond Nijland are both long time participants here. I think it's good they have each others' back.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are retrieving data from just one table and your filter criteria are ...

1. equality on `symbol`
2. range scan low-to-high on `timestamp`.

Therefore, (as Gordon mentioned) an index on two columns `(symbol, timestamp)` can satisfy your query, both the filtering and the ordering, quite efficiently. The query planner will do a random access operation on the index to the correct symbol and the starting timestamp, then read the index sequentially until the ending timestamp.  That's efficient.

But, your `SELECT *` may be holding you back on performance. Why? If you used, for example, `SELECT symbol, timestamp, cusip, name` then you could create a so-called covering index on `(symbol, timestamp, cusip, name)`. In that case, the *entire* query would be satisfied by scanning the index. That can be very efficient indeed.

**Pro tip** Avoid `SELECT *`, both for software stability and performance reasons.

**Pro tip** Don't add extra indexes to a table unless you know they will help particular queries. MySQL only uses a single index for each table in a query or subquery. Neither an index on just `timestamp` or just `symbol` will help much: MySQL still has to examine a lot of rows to satisfy your filtering criteria.

Comment: And, a 50K row result set will definitely consume a lot of resources, both on the DBMS and your client program.  Can you cut it down to a smaller number?

Comment: I try set 5K, 1K, 500 limit - no changes